# How to make a Javascript/React/Typescript fetch call asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, fetch-api

Consider the following Javascript/React code:

```js
// Javascript function that has a fetch call in it. 
export const signIn = (email:string, password:string) => {
  console.log("FETCHING...");

  fetch(`${endPoint}/sign_in`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email,
      password
    })
  })
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(({ data }) => {
    console.log("FETCHED DATA...")
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('ERROR: ', error)
  })

  console.log("DONE FETCHING...");
}

// A functional component that references signIn.
export const SignIn: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  // irrelevant code ...

  const onSubmit = (e: CustomFormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log("SIGNING IN...")
    // calls my signIn function from above
    // I don't want this to finish until the fetch inside it does.
    signIn(email, password, setAuthentication, setCurrentUser)
    console.log("SIGNED IN...");
  }

  return <>A form here submits and calls onSubmit</>
}
```

This produces the following console log output:

```
SIGNING IN...
FETCHING...
DONE FETCHING...
SIGNED IN...
FETCHED DATA...
```

I want `FETCHED DATA...` to show up before `DONE FETCHING...`. I've tried playing around with `aysnc/await` but that's not working so I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look more into how promises in JavaScript works.

One problem here is in `signIn`. What you're doing right now is:

```js
function signIn() {
  // 1. log FETCHING
  // 2. call asynchronous fetch function
  // 3. log DONE FETCHING
}
```

The key here is that `fetch` is *asynchronous*. The program doesn't wait for it to finish before moving on. See the problem? The JavaScript interpreter is going to run step 3 without waiting for step 2 to finish.

There are multiple ways to fix this. First, you can use `then`. Here's an example:

```js
promise
  .then(res => func1(res))
  .then(res => func2(res))
  .then(res => func3(res))
```

Here, you're telling JavaScript to:

1. Run `promise`, and wait for it to *resolve*.
2. Take the result from `promise` and pass it into `func1`. Wait for `func1` to resolve.
3. Take the result from `func1` and pass it into `func2`. Wait for `func2` to resolve.
4. etc.

The key difference here is that you are running each `then` block in order, waiting for each previous promise to be resolved before going to the next one. (Whereas before you didn't wait for the promise to resolve).

Your code with promises would look like:

```js
export const signIn = (email: string, password: string) => {
  console.log("FETCHING...")
  // Note that we return the promise here. You will need this to get onSubmit working.
  return fetch(/* args */)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(({ data }) => console.log("DONE FETCHING"))
    .catch(err => /* HANDLE ERROR */)
}
```

The second way to fix this is to use `async` and `await`. `async` and `await` is simply syntax sugar over promises. What it does underneath is the exact same, so make sure you understand how promises work first. Here's your code with `async` and `await`:

```js
// The async keyword here is important (you need it for await)
export const signIn = async (email: string, password: string) => {
  console.log("FETCHING...");

  try {
    const res = await fetch(/* args */) // WAIT for fetch to finish
    const { data } = res.json()
    console.log("FETCHED DATA...")
  } catch (err) {
    /* HANDLE ERROR */
  }

  console.log("DONE FETCHING...")
}
```

There's also a second similar problem in `onSubmit`. The idea is the same; I'll let you figure it out yourself (the important part is that you must return a `Promise` from `signIn`).

Comment: How would I be able to do this so I didn't have to pass a promise back from `signIn` and instead a kind of `signIn` payload? Could I wrap what I'm doing in `signIn` using another `Promise` and use a typed `resolve/reject`? Let me know if what I'm asking doesn't make sense.

Comment: If you want to return some payload from `signIn`, just wrap the payload in a promise. For example, you can do something like `return fetch(/* ... */).then(/* ... */).then(/* ... */).then(() => ({ some: 'payload' }))` at the end of `signIn`. The payload is then what you get after resolving the return value of `signIn`.

Answer (score 3):

Just add another .then

```
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(({ data }) => {
    console.log("FETCHED DATA...")
    return
  }).then(()=> {
      console.log("DONE FETCHING...");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('ERROR: ', error)
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

It would have to be in the `then` statements if you want the `console.log` to wait until the promise is resolved. Here's an example that uses `async/await`:

```
export const signIn = async (email:string, password:string) => {
  console.log("FETCHING...");

  const response = await fetch(`${endPoint}/sign_in`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email,
      password
    })
  })

  const data = await response.json();

  console.log("FETCHED DATA...")
  console.log("DONE FETCHING...");
}
```

You would also need to turn this into an `async` function if you want the console.log to happen after the data is done fetching:

```
  const onSubmit = async (e: CustomFormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log("SIGNING IN...")
    // calls my signIn function from above
    // I don't want this to finish until the fetch inside it does.
    await signIn(email, password, setAuthentication, setCurrentUser)
    console.log("SIGNED IN...");
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to use async await, you need to return a promise from the call. So basically you don't execute the `.then` and wrap the call in a try catch block.

```
export const signIn = async (email:string, password:string) => {
  console.log("FETCHING...");

  return fetch(`${endPoint}/sign_in`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email,
      password
    })
  })
}
```

and

```
  const onSubmit = async (e: CustomFormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log("SIGNING IN...")
    // calls my signIn function from above
    // I don't want this to finish until the fetch inside it does.
    try {
        const data = await signIn(email, password, setAuthentication, setCurrentUser)
        // Parse data, do something with it. 
        console.log("SIGNED IN...");
    } catch (e) {
        // handle exception 
    }
  }
```